# Efficient query for finding an element in a range

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, pairwise, range-query

I face a problem, where I need to find a specific pairwise sum where the first element from the index has index > `i`.

Example:

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 6]` (index `0` to `4`)

target_sum = 9

Now, from this array I need to find a pairwise sum where the first element from the index has index > `i`.

Now, the obvious solution is:

1. Calculate the pairwise sum array.
   `[1+2, 1+3, 1+4, 1+6, 2+3, 2+4, 2+6, 3+4, 3+6, 4+6]` [ O(n^2) ]
2. Loop through index `i+1` to `n` to find the target_sum. [ O(n^2) ] *(n being the length of original array)*

Now, the main issue is 2. Even if I can't improve (1), I need to improve (2), as this will be queried a lot.

One approach that comes to my mind:

1. Make an array of index, value pair from the pairwise sum array. O(n^2) *[n being the original length]*
2. Sort the array first with value, then with index. O(n^2 * logn)
3. For each query, run a binary search to find the interval where the value exists. O(logn)
4. Run another binary search on that interval to find the index > `i`.

Is there any elegant and better approach?

Comment: Try to use hashmap/ dictionary to solve this.

Comment: @DanielHao can you explain how? (npi)

Comment: I think you already got the answer below - see the latest post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a map `sum -> highest first element index` in `O(n^2)`. Then answer each query in `O(1)` by looking up the target sum in the map and deciding if `highest first element index` is higher than `i`.